# update divs content at the same time (nested ajax calls)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two divs on a page like this:

```
<div id="content_1"></div>
<div id="content_2"></div>
```

The content of those two divs are update via Ajax by doing something like this:

```
$('#content_1').load('content_1_url', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'content_2_url', 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content_2').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see above, the content of `content_1` comes from the returned result of the ajax call to the url `content_1_url`, and the content of `content_2` comes from the returned result of the ajax call to the url `content_2_url`. This works fine, but the problem I have is that the content of each div is not updated at the exact same time on the page. The first div content shows first and then one second later the content of the second div appears. I want them to appear at the same time. Any idea how I can fix this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about that:

```
var ajax1 =  $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'content_1_url'
 }), ajax2 = $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'content_2_url'
 });

$.when(ajax1,ajax2).done(function(data1,data2){
    $('#content1').html(data1[0]); 
    $('#content2').html(data2[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var res1, res2;
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'content_1_url', success: function(data){res1 = data;}, async: false});
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: 'content_2_url', success: function(data){res2 = data;}, async: false});
$('#content1').html(res1);
$('#content2').html(res2);
```

Comment: Is there anyway this can be done without setting `async=false`?

Comment: Yes sir, @roasted answer is doing this without `async=false`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.when($.ajax("content_1_url"), $.ajax("content_1_url"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);

function myFunc(){
//This execute after both ajax calls finish ok
}

function myFailure(){
//This execute after either ajax calls fails
}
```

I edited this is the complete code (from jquery oficial documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) just change page1.php and page2.php to yours urls:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1, a2){
  /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the
      page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively. 
      each argument is an array with the following 
      structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ] */
  var data = a1[0] + a2[0]; /* a1[0] = "Whip", a2[0] = " It" */
  if ( /Whip It/.test(data) ) {
    alert("We got what we came for!");
  }
});
```